# nuwave/lighthouse: Undefined index: id

Tags: graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm observing wierd behaviour with @json directive. I have an laravel application and Graphql calls are handled using nuwave/lighthouse. I have user table and one of the column in this table is json data which stores user hobbies in different language.

to be more precise:

```
column name: language_mapping
type: json
data structure: { hobbies : { en: "", de: "", da: ""}}
```

**What is working?**

Below update query works well and updates only specic language under hobbies.

```
GraphQL mutation:

mutation {  updateLanguageSpecificUsers(user_id: 33, language_mapping: "hobbies.en=singing") {    
    language_mapping {      
        hobbies {        
            en          
        }          
    }     
}
}
```

I understood that this line `@json(columns: ["language_mapping"], model: Users)` is responsible for updating the right key with the value.

```
Users.graphql file

extend type Mutation {
  updateLanguageSpecificUsers(
    language_mapping: Mixed
    user_id: Int @rules(apply: ["numeric"])
  ): Users @json(columns: ["language_mapping"], model: Users) @update
}
```

**What is not working?**

I want to create an record if record not present else update the record if its present so, I created one more mutation for create or update but when I run the query, I'm getting       `"debugMessage": "Undefined index: id", "file": "/var/www/dummy/api/app/GraphQL/Directives/JsonDirective.php",`

```
mutation { 
  updateOrCreateLanguageSpecificUsers(language_mapping: "hobbies.en=singing", user_id: 4171){
     language_mapping {      
        hobbies {        
            en          
        }          
    }      
  }
}
```

```
Users.graphql file

extend type Mutation {
  updateOrCreateLanguageSpecificUsers(
    language_mapping: Mixed
    user_id: Int @rules(apply: ["numeric"])
  ): Users @json(columns: ["language_mapping"], model: Users) @updateOrCreate(search: ["user_id"])
)
```

I couldn't understand whats going wrong in this mutation.

I would like to update or create based on presence of data.

Comment: I don't find the directive @updateOrCreate in lighthouse [directives](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#directives).

Comment: What does this have to do with Laravel or PHP?

Comment: @miken32 you can create [resolvers](https://lighthouse-php.com/6/api-reference/resolvers.html#resolver-function-signature) with PHP language, and use laravel [relationships](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/eloquent/relationships.html#eloquent-relationships). The lighthouse lib is to be used with php and laravel. You can use `graphql` with many [languages](https://graphql.org/code/) and frameworks.

Comment: @miken32 It's nuwave/lightho use directive. You can find a few examples here in this issue. https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/issues/2091

Comment: @miken32 one more here. https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse-docs/blob/master/docs/assets/tutorial/flow.png

Comment: As you can see from the path to the directive: `/var/www/dummy/api/app/GraphQL/Directives/JsonDirective.php`. The directive is not provided by Lighthouse (otherwise it would be in the vendor folder) so without posting the code of the custom directives (both @json and @updateOrCreate are not part of Lighthouse) we can't help you!